# How to Handle Javascript Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous

This my code

```
encrypt(plaintxt){
    const secretKey = '12456780123456';
    const iv = "124567890123456";

    let a = "awal";
    AesCrypto.encrypt(plaintxt,secretKey,iv).then(cipher=>{
        a = cipher;
    }).catch(err=>{
        a = err;
    });
    return a;
}
```

How i can set value for variable a in the AesCrypto.encrypt function? Thanks.

Comment: @Paulpro so, what the solution if you think its duplicated? i cannot found the solution from your link.

Comment: Just `return AesCrypto.encrypt(plaintxt,secretKey,iv);`. That will return the Promise properly, and as the duplicates explain in detail that is what you want.

Comment: The first duplicate explains why `a` isn't modified yet when you do `return a;`. The second duplicate explains why you don't want to return `a` at all and instead want to return a Promise from your function.

Answer (score 1):

The `AesCrypto.encrypt()` is asynchronous, which means that if you want to return the value of `a` from your `encrypt()` function using the structure you've defined above, then you'll need to [define it as an asynchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) like so:

```
/* Declare the function as asynchronous with async keyword */
function async encrypt(plaintxt){
    const secretKey = '124567980123456';
    const iv = "1234567890123456";


    /* Create a promoise and wait for it to complete (or fail)
    using the await keyword */
    const a = await (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        /* Resolve or reject the promise by passing the handlers
        to your promise handlers */
        AesCrypto.encrypt(plaintxt,secretKey,iv)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
    }))

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Why wrap `AesCrypto.encrypt` inside a Promise? from what i see `AesCrypto.encrypt`  already returns a promise

Comment: I get this error " value for title cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to String" in my react-native project

Comment: There is no point using await only to immediately return the awaited value. Just return the original Promise instead of awaiting it, and using the Promise constructor when you already have a Promise is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

use `async await` for that

```
async encrypt(plaintxt){
    const secretKey = '124567980123456';
    const iv = "1234567890123456";

    let a = "awal";
    a = await AesCrypto.encrypt(plaintxt,secretKey,iv);

    return a;
}
```

Comment: in your first answer, the return value still null/empty string. And in your second answer, i got "value for title cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to String" in my react-native project.

Comment: @BroskySamsonPutrahalimI have removed that answer because it's wrong for what you want.

Comment: No problem @Shashin Bhayani. Have another solution? Thanks

Comment: There is no point using await only to immediately return the awaited value. Just return the original Promise instead of awaiting it.

Comment: @shashinBhayani please provide a proper description